# Is is there any framework that integrates Kendo UI and Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

I'm started using Kendo UI on my project and i want to integrate it with Bootstrap to have responsible design.
I wonder, Is there any framework that integrates Kendo and Bootstrap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you can use [BootstrapForKendoUI](https://github.com/advancedrei/BootstrapForKendoUI)

Answer (score 0):

kendo UI already has a BootStrap compatible design. http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/web.html

select the Bootstrap theme from the select list